# My controller keep on returning the error "The requested resource is not available"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, localhost, controllers

I have this controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addr")
public class AddressController
{

   public List<Address> addresses = (List<Address>) Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<Address>());

   @RequestMapping("/new")
   public String getAddressForm()
   {
     return "addressProject/addressBook";
   }

   @RequestMapping("/submit")
   public ModelAndView submitForm(String name, String email, String group, String phoneNumber, String address){
      Address addr = new Address(name, email, group, phoneNumber, address);
      addresses.add(addr);

      ModelAndView modelandview = new          ModelAndView("/addressproject/newAddress");

      return modelandview;      
   }
}
```

and for some reason the localhost only shows The requested resource is not available.

I'm using the correct url which is http://localhost:8080/ExampleSpringWebApp/smvc/addr/new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that http://localhost:8080/ExampleSpringWebApp/smvc/addr/new is the correct URL? I don't see `smvc` anywhere in your @RequestMapping annotation. What about http://localhost:8080/ExampleSpringWebApp/addr/new ?

Is your @Controller class being instantiated by spring? Do you have `<context:component-scan />` and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your spring context?

Do you have a view "addressProject/addressBook"? Can it be found by the ViewResolver? What's the exact error message?

The ClassCastException

> nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection cannot be cast to java.util.List

results from you calling Collections.synchronizedCollection, but casting it to List. Collections.synchronizedCollection() **returns a Collection - no List**. Please change it to

```
 public Collection<Address> addresses = (Collection<Address>) Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<Address>());
```

Comment: I've tried both the links and nether work and sorry I'm not sure how to check the other two. This is my first ever web app project.

Comment: [First link](http://gyazo.com/b8050ac43883c069551e21617ab1b3d7) and [Second link](http://gyazo.com/04ee29d52fe2294422ca1b069269eee9)

Comment: If you add a constructor `public class AddressController() {System.out.println("Hello World");}` and restart your application, is "Hello World" printed to your catalina.out? If not, I guess that spring doesn't initialize your Controller. You'll then probably have to add `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.that.contains.the.controller"/>` and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to you applicationContext.xml

Comment: I've search my entire workspace and there in no file named applicationContext.xml. Thanks for the help by the way, really appreciate it.

Comment: do you have any xml file that defines an application context? Please look for an xml file containing `<beans`. If you cannot find it, you might need to set up a spring application from scratch.

Comment: Ah I've added <context:component-scan base-package="AddressBook"/> and <mvc:annotation-driven/> to my xml file, but now I'm getting this. [error](http://gyazo.com/c1cebd5228eb7dedbfda1cf40d6a4bff)

Comment: What's the exact StackTrace? The screenshot cuts off the root cause. Please paste the full stackTrace in your original comment (no screenshots)

Comment: Oh sorry about that. This is the whole error. [link](http://pastebin.com/uKGLVvF7) :)

Comment: That worked perfect, however now its saying [this](http://gyazo.com/e63b9023e2c92606420d9de9b63eb7ec) when this file is clearly present [here](http://gyazo.com/3414c9f7d2bfc65301e010276f6dda33). I'm really sorry about all these problems, I really appreciate you helping. :)

Comment: Ignore that previous message, its just started work. Thank you